# issue in understanding `WebSocketServer` is not a class

Tags: node.js

I am implementing the websockets and installed the ws package also in my project but when  initialise the `const WSS= new WebSocketServer({port: 3232}),` the typeError is showing `WebSocketServer is not a constructor` error.

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').server;
const WSS = new WebSocketServer({port: 3232});

WSS.on('connection',(ws)=>{
  console.log('we are connected');
});
```

typeError is shown `webSocketServer is not a constructor`

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the es module, try this:

```
import { WebSocketServer } from "ws";

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true });
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `ws.Server` in the ESM version, use `import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws'` instead.

credit : [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1538#issuecomment-944859160)

Answer (score 1):

It's `.Server`, not `.server`.

Here's an example:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  port: 8080
})
```

or to keep your format:

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const WSS = new WebSocketServer({port: 3232});

WSS.on('connection',(ws)=>{
  console.log('we are connected');
});
```